# scrape data through xpath from div that contains javascript in scrapy python

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, scrapy

I am working on scrapy , i am scraping a site and using `xpath` to scrape items.
But some of the `div` contains `javascript`, so when i used xpath until the `div id` that contains javascript code is returning an empty list,and without including that div element(which contains javascript) can able to fetch HTML data

HTML code

```
<div class="subContent2">    
   <div id="contentDetails">
       <div class="eventDetails">
            <h2>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="jdevents.getEvent(117032)">Some data</a>
            </h2>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Spider Code

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    domain_name = "www.example.com"
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/jkl/index.php"]


    def parse(self, response):
         hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
         required_data = hxs.select('//div[@class="subContent2"]/div[@id="contentDetails"]/div[@class="eventDetails"]')
```

So how can i get `text(Some data)` from the `anchor tag` inside the `h2 element` as mentioned above, is there any alternate way for fetching data from the elements that contains javascript in scrapy

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="subContent2">    
   <div id="contentDetails">
       <div class="eventDetails">
            <h2>
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="jdevents.getEvent(117032)">Some data</a>
            </h2>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is not the javascript code in this case to get 'Some data' string.

You need either to get the subnode:

```
required_data = hxs.select('//div[@class="subContent2"]/div[@id="contentDetails"]/div[@class="eventDetails"]/h2/a/text()')
```

[image]

or use `string` function:

```
required_data = hxs.select('string(//div[@class="subContent2"]/div[@id="contentDetails"]/div[@class="eventDetails"])')
```

Comment: :Thanks for u r reply,i got an empty unicode string as below when i used string function  [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='string(//div[@class="subContent2"]/div[@id="contentDetails"]/div[@class="eventDetails"]/h2/a/text())' data=u''>]